# Can I intercept a file upload over HTTP to IIS7 and deny the upload based on a validation criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, post, file-upload

I have a form which you can post a file over to my server.

Is there a way, without using a custom HTTP handler, to intercept the start of the post and prevent it before the file is uploaded and bandwidth used up.

So for example, I could check an IP address and if it's blocked in my system I could stop the request before I waste 10MB of uploading.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: You'll get a more specific answer if you indicate which programming language(s) or tools you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a job for a HttpModule, not a HttpHandler. Just check remote IP against a blacklist in the BeginRequest event and null route or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, this isn't possible with stock .NET code, unless you spend time to recreate the file handling and parsing ASP.NET does.

Answer (score -1):

In ASP.Net 2.0, a new [FileUpload control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/FileUpload10092005172118PM/FileUpload.aspx?ArticleID=79850d6d-0e91-4d7b-9e27-a64a09b0ee6b) was added that can be used to limit file types and sizes, among other things.